# How to show interstitial ad in webview after some interval or 3-4 click?

Tags: android, webview, onclick, admob, interstitial

I have a wordpress website and of which I have a webview app and I have implemented interstitial ad on any button click, so whenever a link is clicked full page ads gets shown, How do I decrease it's frequency, I want it to come well let's say after 3 or 4 click?

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // The webView is about to navigate to the specified url.
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .build();
                        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution to my problem, any suggestion most welcome...

```
int n = 1;
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // The webView is about to navigate to the specified url.

                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    if( n%3 == 0 )
                    {
                        interstitialAd.show();

           } n++;
                }
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .build();
                        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show Google interstitial you need to apply some conditions. First of all you have to make a static variable and set its value as one

```
static counter = 1;

if (counter == 3){
// your interstitial code basically call its method show such as ad.show()
counter++;
}
else if (counter == 4){
// your interstitial code basically call its method show such as ad.show()
counter = 1;
}
else{
counter += 1;
}
```

**Edited The Following**

```
public static counter = 1;
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // The webView is about to navigate to the specified url.
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if(counter == 3)
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .build();
                        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
            }
counter = 1;
}else{
  counter++;
}
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

Comment: Could you fit your block in to my code, I did not get what you wanted to say. Above code is how it shows interstitial ad at every click.